# How to convert List<T> into T[,]

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on creating a map editor for a game, and I've come across a bit of a complication. I'm using a Multidimensional Tile array (Tile[,]) to store the tiles that are drawn on the map workspace, and to save these to XML, I am using the following code:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Tile[,] Tiles { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Tile")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public List<Tile> TileList
{
    get
    {
        var tiles = new List<Tile>();
        for (var x = 0; x < Tiles.GetLength(0); x ++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < Tiles.GetLength(1); y ++)
            {
                tiles.Add(Tiles[x, y]);
            }
        }
        return tiles;
    }
}
```

This code lets me successfully convert any maps I create into XML format. Tiles hold the source tileset image location as a string, the source Point location of the tileset image, and the tile's Point location on the map. Other attributes are successfully stored such as tile flags.

The problem is, when I want to deserialize this XML file so that I can load maps, it has trouble when it reaches the TileList property. What I want to do is convert the `List<Tile>` that is read in to a `List[,]`.

The reason I have decided to approach the usage of a multidimensional array to store the tiles is because it is easier and faster to use in the program. Using a List to do this will cause the program to slow considerably when more tiles are added to the map workspace.

Comment: Did you consider implementing `set` part of `TileList` property?

Comment: Yes. The main issue when I do this is the fact I can't grab the width and height of the map so that I can create a `Tile[,]` with those properties. When I add layers to my map, it creates an empty `Tile[,]` with the following code:

`Layer.Tiles = new Tile[(int) Math.Floor((double) (MapSize.Width / TileSize)), (int) Math.Floor((double) (MapSize.Height / TileSize))]`

Comment: Why don't you store these values within the class? It looks like you're trying to recreate your state without having all necessary data available.

Comment: Unless you stored the dimensions somewhere (or can calculate), you can't turn a `List<Tile>` into a `Tile[,]`, because you don't know how many are in each dimension. E.g. if there were 4 tiles, is it 1x4, 2x2, or 4x1?

Comment: I have tried, but upon using the `set` part of the `TileList` property, I receive a "divide by zero" error - it doesn't retrieve the map size and tile size values.

Comment: @TimS. I store the X and Y position that each tile is located within the `Tile` itself.

Comment: What have you tried? What can you do providing you know the dimensions of the aray when deserializing from XML?

Comment: When I serialize, I save the map size, the tile size and then the `List<Layer>`. Every Layer has a `Tile[,]` - the dimensions of the `Tile[,]` is known based on the Map size and tile size, which is known when creating a new map. The map size and tile size is serialized to XML but I can't retrieve them to determine the dimensions of the array when using the `set` part of the TileList property.

Comment: `"it doesn't retrieve the map size and tile size values."`  As @MarcinJuraszek says, you must store that info.  If you are having trouble retrieving it, take a look at the [Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order.aspx) property of the XmlElementAttribute.

Comment: Alright - I've just tried that, storing the map and tile size in order 1 and 2, but when attempting to deserialize, the MapSize and TileSize attributes aren't stored. When I read the XML file, I can see that it is storing the MapSize and TileSize attributes before the Tile List, but I still get "divide by zero" errors when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just something like this?

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Tile[,] Tiles { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Tile")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public List<Tile> TileList
{
    /* existing code */
    set
    {
        Tiles = new Tile[MapWidth, MapHeight];
        for(int i=0;i < value.Count;i++) {
            int x = i % mapWidth;
            int y = i / mapWidth; // integer division truncates so this is ok

            Tiles[x, y] = value[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Width and Height of the map is by default 480x480, but I can define a new size whenever I create new maps. When I save the maps, it serializes all data as such:

Map:
    List<Layer>:
        List<Tile>

The problem is, when I deserialize this data, I have no idea how to get the Map Width and Height so Tile can use it.

Comment: Integer division truncates, which is different from rounding down.  For example -1 / 2 is 0 rather than -1.

Comment: @KevinDeLorey - yes, I know it truncates, hence the "rounding down" in scare quotes. I'll change the answer to say truncates. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Dragonphase - yeah. You'll have to store the map width as a separate piece of data (you can then use it to calculate the height) - there's not really any other way to do it unless you modify your tiles so there's a "end of line" tile or something like that